# Why $('#file-input').click() does not open file input dialog when called in browser console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-io, triggers

I found this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QVAC7/ which help me to open the file input dialog. The idea is simple:

**HTML**:

```
<button id="id">Open</button>
<input id="yourinputname" type="file" name="yourinputname" style="display: none;" />
```

**JS**:

```
$('#id').on('click', function() {
    $('#yourinputname').trigger('click');
});
```

The code works fine, when I click the button, a dialog showed up.

But there is a strange thing that when I enter the same command to the Chrome console, the dialog did not show up.

```
$('#yourinputname').trigger('click');
```

[image: he dialog did not show up]

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: @David, wow that's strange. I tried this with Chrome 39 on OS X and Windows and it doesn't work. What browser/version/environment are your?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the console to try and find the jQuery object associated with `$('#yourinputname')` inside the JSFiddle, you won't find it because the JSFiddle's "Result" section is located inside an iFrame, which contains this code's "Result" in a secondary document outside the scope of the JSFiddle app.

You won't be able to run code from the console in this manner until you take the important code from this Fiddle, insert it into a page somewhere, and run it yourself.

Comment: If you look close enough, the screenshot shows the input element is in fact returned by the statement.

Comment: @Matthew, I'm not sure if his screenshot is actually reflecting the Fiddle, or if he actually added it to his page and took a screenshot of that.  If you goto the JSFiddle page and try typing $('#yourinputname') into the console, you get a NULL result.

Comment: But I guess he won't take a screenshot of a working console output and label "nothing happens".   So just wondering if this is the actual cause.

Comment: @EdwardCoyleJr. I know about JSFiddle uses iframes, and I did not run the code inside the JSFiddle page. That screenshot was taken when I run the code in my page (I created a simple HTML file with jQuery, and run the code in console, you can try it yourself). Do you have any idea?

Comment: Just for completeness: it is possible to run console code on jsFiddle. You just have to select the "result( fiddle.jshell.net/ )" frame in the drop down (stating "<top frame>" in the screenshot)